# what is the acceptable value for acceptable cut point while minimizes distance between ROC plot and point (0,1)

Tags: roc

If we would like to find the optimal cut point using minimizes distance between ROC plot and point (0,1), is it a acceptable value in the field for the roc01 value? I have searched for the reference and could not find one. Could anyone give some guidance on this?

Comment: You say "point (0,1)" but do you mean the identity line - i.e. the ROC of the "worthless predictor"? I think you would rather *maximize* the distance from this line, and from which point distance is measured, geometrically, introduces as much nuance/confusion as not meeting this criterion at all. When measured orthogonally, WLOG you can just choose the maximum of (sensitivity + specificity)^2. That doesn't make a good cut off in general, a false negative is rarely exactly worth a false positive.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated!  Your question refers to "...a acceptable value in the field for the roc01 value" which implies that you are using a specific implementation of an ROC.  It might be helpful to include information on what software you are using and perhaps add a tag so to get an answer to your question.

Comment: I am using `cutpointr` package to find optimal cut points. for other matric, I can find the reference, such as `Youden Index: 0.85 indicate that the diagnostic accuracy of the test is excellent`, `kappa below 0.60 indicates inadequate agreement `. But for `roc01: minimizes distance between ROC plot and point (0,1)`, how can we tell how good or bad the test? any reference value we can use for judgement?

Comment: @AdamO point (0,1) would be the top left corner, so the perfect ROC curve.

Comment: @stataq I don't really understand what you are asking, but this might help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/483289/36682